# Android Glance widget: how to retrieve configuration when "reconfiguring" widget?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

Using Jetpack Compose "Glance" package (in alpha-0.0.5, beta-01 bugged for me) : is it possible to retrieve the "Configuration data" added at the "widget creation" when displaying the "widget update/reconfigure" screen using the `AppWidgetConfigurationScaffold` ?

The idea is to re-select/auto-fill the fields with the previous/original data ..

```
@Composable
private fun ConfigurationScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val configurationState = rememberAppWidgetConfigurationState(RowWidget)

    fun updatePref() {
        configurationState.updateCurrentState<Preferences> {
            it.toMutablePreferences().apply {
                set(WidgetReceiver.data, selectedData)
            }.toPreferences()
        }
    }

    if (configurationState.glanceId == null) {
        configurationState.discardConfiguration()
        return
    }

    // auto-select previous value
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

        val currentData = configurationState.getCurrentState<Preferences>()
            ?.get(WidgetReceiver.data)
        
        // HERE currentData should not be null and I should get back the "data" when creating the widget
        if (currentData != null) {
            selectedData = currentData
            updatePref()
        }
    }

    AppWidgetConfigurationScaffold(...)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually Glance was totally OK and found back the data automatically.

The mistake was on my side with LaunchedEffect getting exec only once when `configurationState` is not yet ready :

```
val previousData = configurationState.getCurrentState<Preferences>()?.get(WidgetReceiver.prefKey)
LaunchedEffect(previousData) {
   // init/fill form with previous data
}
```